# How to disable export textarea in GridView?

Tags: gridview, yii2

I'd like to disable following textarea(look at my attachement,please) of kartik export

**Completing question:**
Following code in \vendor\kartik-v\yii2-grid\GridView.php is responsible for this textarea

```
         Html::textarea('export_content') . "\n" .
```

[image]

I want to use export options, of course. I just don't want print out textarea. Any ideas, how to achieve my intention?

**Remarking:**
This thread has been succesfully solved of Muhammad Omer Aslam. Affectionate regards to him!

Comment: could be you are not showing the right part of code .. seems that there is not code related  to export options in your code

Comment: Yes, it is. Look at my toolbar-array!

Comment: are you sure you have not   proper widget for export  ??  or you are using some gridview extension??  eg kartik gridview or similar??

Comment: I completed question: Using export of kartik! Be carful of first two sentences of my question.Thx!

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: no problem i removed the view code from the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isnt any `textarea` shown by using `kartik/gridview` export but yes it creates a form in which multiple inputs are created regarding the export menu where this textarea is also added as the last element in the form, but the form has the inline style property `display:none` see below form

```
<form class="kv-export-form" action="http://www.potentialpads.local/gridview/export/download" method="post" style="display:none;" target="kvDownloadDialog">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf-frontend" value="-Bk4vWoeSOh-9gA-VlWI-FaxZV9LqavuLl46mQncILVEAIss4VQ3aRBwBgy_svmKoQKrwm2DFLpjmKbd6HOzPw==">
<input type="hidden" name="module_id" value="gridview">
<input type="hidden" name="export_hash">
<input type="hidden" name="export_filetype">
<input type="hidden" name="export_filename">
<input type="hidden" name="export_mime">
<input type="hidden" name="export_config">
<input type="hidden" name="export_encoding" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="export_bom" value="1">
<textarea name="export_content"></textarea>
</form>
```

So What you problem is that you are wrapping the `GridView` inside the

```
Html::beginForm(['/mail/mail-ausgang/sendallmails'], 'post', ['name' => 'document']);
Html::endForm();
```

You need to move the gridview outside because What you are trying to do will break and render the HTML invalid.

Because you are trying to wrap `GridView` inside a `form`

GridView has its own filter form as i mentioned above generated by `Yii` so this will result in nested HTML forms which is `INVALID HTML`.

You cannot keep the Gridview inside the form.

Comment: Won't fix problem. I added rule into my local file using <style></style> tag and in same file I added:$this->registerCss('form.kv-export-form ,form.kv-export-form >textarea {display:none !important;}');

Comment: @tklustig that is strange can you temporarily disble theme files and try loading the page and see does it displays the textarea with the default css files for `kartik/gridview`

Comment: A lot of textareas ,all are hidden, except one! If I push button All(Alle in my attachement) textarea will disappear!

Comment: @tklustig did you tried that after disabling the theme css files ?

Comment: Disabling all css-elements in firedebug won't let disappear textarea!

Comment: you are using adminLTE if i am not wrong ? have you used any extension for adminLTE or manually configured it theme diles are the css files that are used by adminLTE

Comment: No, I didn't change css files of adminlte at all. Css rules are origin!! I only use adminlte and bootstrap css files, without having defined own rules globally

Comment: i am asking you to temporarily disable those css files ti be sure they are the one causing the textarea to be visible

Comment: If I deactivate all css elements in firedebug, textare won't disappear. Is that what u mean with temporarily disabling?

Comment:  no COMMENT OUT THE CSS FILES, i wonder how hard it could be to understand

Comment: I only load one css file in my AssetClass:css/AdminLTE.min.css Commenting out this file will destroy my website optically!

Comment: dude i am asking to disable it temporarily for troubleshooting it not to remove it permanently.

Comment: I commented out almost all css files being loaded temporarily, for instance kv.grid-expand.css. textare won't disappear:=(

Comment: add your complete view in the Question all the code inside the view i suspect you are wrapping the gridview inside a form @tklustig

Comment: Great ! U are the BEST! Textarea will be disappeared after having set GridView outsifde of form ! Gave U reputation points for ur efforts. Go ahead!!

Comment: Colud U delete publishing my code, please?! I'm not sure about this:=(